# Excel graphs: how can I update the series for multiple graphs in one go?

Tags: excel, automation, graph, charts

I have 5 graphs on a tab refering to Sheet ABC. I am duplicationg the tab with the graphs and then making this new set refer to Sheet DEF. The series ranges are exactly the same, it's just the name of the tab that changes.

It's taking a while to go through all the series and replcaing the ABC with DEF. I tried a find and replace and it wasn't successful (I don't know why). Is there another way of changing the series reference in one go? Or is there a trick with find and replace.

Original reference

```
=SERIES('ABCData'!$C$3,'ABCData'!$A$4:$A$34,'ABCData'!$C$4:$C$34,2)
```

New reference

```
=SERIES('DEFData'!$C$3,'DEFData'!$A$4:$A$34,'DEFData'!$C$4:$C$34,2)
```

Many thanks

Michael.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normal find and replace will do it. Make sure Look In is set to Formulas in the advanced section.

Comment: maybe I missed that but I was sure I checked it. I've done it all manually now, so I'll be slightly peeved if it was that little ommission. Ah well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote myself a little add-in to allow me to make such find and replace adjustments to chart series formulas. I liked it so well, I've made it available free for anyone. The link to the add-in is near the end of this tutorial on my blog:

[Change Series Formula - Improved Routines](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/change-series-formula-improved-routines/)